# Using TestContext.TestName in Managed C++ Tests

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, managed-c++

How can I use the TestName member of the TestContext class in managed VS C++ test code to automatically output the name of the test method to the debug console?

Every example I've been able to find is in C# and I cannot translate it into C++ properly.  Here I attempt to do this by capturing a TestContext object during the static ClassInitialize method, but this does not work.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public ref class SampleTestClass
{

public:

    [TestMethod]
    void testMethod1()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    void testMethod2()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    void testMethod3()
    {

    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    Tests Setup and Teardown                                                                                    //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    static TestContext^ myTestContext;

    [TestInitialize]
    void testCaseInitialize()
    {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        std::wstring testName = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>( myTestContext->TestName );
        std::wstring dbgSend = L"initializing " + testName;
        ::OutputDebugString( dbgSend.c_str() );
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    void testCaseCleanup()
    {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        std::wstring testName = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>( myTestContext->TestName );
        std::wstring dbgSend = L"tearing down " + testName;
        ::OutputDebugString( dbgSend.c_str() );
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    static void testClassInitialize( TestContext^ context )
    {
        myTestContext = context;
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    static void testClassCleanup()
    {

    }



};
```

Output

```
[9404] initializing testMethod1
[9404] tearing down testMethod1
[9404] initializing testMethod1
[9404] tearing down testMethod1
[9404] initializing testMethod1
[9404] tearing down testMethod1
```

Desired Output

```
[9404] initializing testMethod1
[9404] tearing down testMethod1
[9404] initializing testMethod2
[9404] tearing down testMethod2
[9404] initializing testMethod3
[9404] tearing down testMethod3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague answered the question for me.  The framework will automatically set the test context for you if you create a public member property named TestInstance.  Here is the exact syntax that works for me.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public ref class SampleTestClass
{

public:

    [TestMethod]
    void testMethod1()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    void testMethod2()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    void testMethod3()
    {

    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    Tests Setup and Teardown                                                                                    //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private:
    TestContext^ myTestContextInstance;

    public:
    property TestContext^ TestContext
    {

        virtual Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ get()
        {
            return myTestContextInstance;
        }

        virtual void set( Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ value)
        {
            myTestContextInstance = value;
        }
    }


    [TestInitialize]
    void testCaseInitialize()
    {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        std::wstring testName = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>( myTestContextInstance->TestName );
        std::wstring dbgSend = L"initializing " + testName;
        ::OutputDebugString( dbgSend.c_str() );
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    void testCaseCleanup()
    {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        std::wstring testName = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>( myTestContextInstance->TestName );
        std::wstring dbgSend = L"tearing down " + testName;
        ::OutputDebugString( dbgSend.c_str() );
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    static void testClassInitialize( Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestContext^ context )
    {

    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    static void testClassCleanup()
    {

    }

};
```

Comment: You wrote `TestInstance` in your text, but `TestContext` in your code.